# What is the difference between At( ) function and subscript operator in c++ string?

Tags: c++, string, std

I was wondering why would someone use the At method to access a character at a particular index of std::string instead of a simple subscript operator?

like to access a character at the 3rd index we can simply use str[3] instead of str.At(3). Is there an advantage or disadvantage either of these posses?

Comment: There is no such method charAt in C++.

Comment: There is no `charAt` in `std::string`, only `at`.

Comment: The [at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) function performs bounds checking.